# How to parse SVG source file by groups

Tags: objective-c, parsing, svg, cocos2d-iphone, inkscape

I'm creating levels for my game and using Inkscape and SVG for source file format. I can parse object one by one but not in group, lets say if i want parse only group "objects_2" How to do it?

```
  <g id="objects_1">
    <object y="100" x="65" height="40" width="40" />
    <object width="40" height="40" x="212" y="200" />
    <object y="105" x="355" height="40" width="40" />
  </g>

  <g id="objects_2">
    <object y="150" x="100" height="40" width="40" />
  </g>
```

Comment: read it all in, then iterate over the in-memory xml. depends on how you load the xml, ie nsxmldocument or tinyxml

Comment: thanks @LearnCocos2D could you give me link to show how to do that.. here is my code to iterate over each element http://pastie.org/7670654

Comment: Create a class SVGObject with x,y,width,height (or just a CGRect). Create an instance for every group, and put it in a dictionary with the group id as key. Then you have them all in memory, and can access individual groups in the dictionary by their key. XML is bad for random access, therefore you need to create an in-memory representation of the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate the DOM structure, two quick ways of doing this:

1. **jQuery** `var svgObject = jQuery('#objects_1')` and `svgObject[0]` returns the first object

**javascript** `var svgObject = document.getElementById('objects_1')` and `svgObject.children[0]` is the first child object

If you are already familiar with jQuery, stick to it since switching between native JS and jQuery can be confusing, especially when syntax is similar.